# Apache Commons Net Slow FTP Upload

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I'm using Apache Commons Net 3.3 to handle FTP transfers in a Java application.

Downloads seem to work fine, but I'm getting speeds a lot slower than the local internet connection capabilities for uploads.

The code that writes the file data to the stream looks like this:

```
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(ftp.getOutputStream(prt));
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(prov.getInputStream(s));
        byte[] buff = new byte[BUFF_SIZE];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buff)) >= 0 && !prog.isCanceled()) {
            out.write(buff, 0, len);
            total += len;
            prog.setProgress((int) (Math.round((total / combo) * 100)));
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
```

BUFF_SIZE = 16kB

I have the FTPClient buffer size also set to 16kB via `setBufferSize`

The issue isn't with the server or my internet connection because the upload proceeds at a much more reasonable speed using Filezilla as a FTP client.

The issue also seems to occur with Java 6 and 7 JVMs.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?  Is there a problem with Commons Net or Java?  Or is there something I haven't configured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem - using SDK 1.6 resolve problem, but also try to find better way

UPD: Solved (see comments)

Comment: I think I did end up fixing this, and the problem was basically just with the default implementation of InputStream/OutputStream being extremely slow. So maybe try overriding more of its methods.

Comment: The problem in my case was because im using Virtualbox for testing. 
On real machine - all fine. Spend all day for that )